# Find the probability of getting 2 golden coins from a bag of 4 golden coins and 8 iron coins with the following conditions:

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are 4 golden coins and 8 iron coins in a bag. You select one coin from the bag, if it is a golden coin, you keep it; but if it is an iron coin, you put it back in the bag. Find the probability of earning **exactly 2 golden coins** after three consecutive attempt.

---

My Try:

Golden Coins=4

Iron coins = 8

Total coins = 12

We have 3 cases here: (GIG, GGI, IGG)

$ (\frac{4}{12}\times \frac{8}{11}\times \frac{3}{11})+(\frac{4}{12}\times \frac{3}{11}\times \frac{8}{10})+(\frac{8}{12}\times \frac{4}{12}\times \frac{3}{11}) = \frac{362}{1815} $

Is this answer correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Good job!

Comment: Change your question as an asnwer to close it

Comment: @Semiclassical I am suffering the same problem, I think my answer is wrong, but can't find why.

Comment: @DanielMuñoz How do I even do that If I had to?

Comment: After bug-fixing, my simulation agrees with the result of 362/1815 that you obtain. So I think you're in the clear.

Comment: @NitinRattu when you choose to modify your questions, select the square "answer my own questions" below the field of your formatted text and above of the submit o modify button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 3 cases here: (GIG, GGI, IGG)

Every time that we take out a golden ball(G), we subtract 1 from the total balls.

Every time we take out an iron ball(I), we don't subtract anything because the ball goes back into the bag.

So, for  (GIG, GGI, IGG), we have:

$ (\frac{4}{12}\times \frac{8}{11}\times \frac{3}{11})+(\frac{4}{12}\times \frac{3}{11}\times \frac{8}{10})+(\frac{8}{12}\times \frac{4}{12}\times \frac{3}{11}) = \frac{362}{1815} $